# getting date of change based on column values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
fid         date       stage
test_fid    4/22/2019   a1
test_fid    4/23/2019   a1
test_fid    4/24/2019   a2
test_fid    4/25/2019   a2
test_fid    4/26/2019   a2
test_fid    4/27/2019   a3
test_fid    4/28/2019   a3
test_fid    4/29/2019   a3
test_fid1   4/30/2019   a1
test_fid1   5/1/2019    a1
test_fid1   5/2/2019    a1
test_fid1   5/3/2019    a1
test_fid1   5/4/2019    a2
test_fid1   5/5/2019    a2
test_fid1   5/6/2019    a2
test_fid1   5/7/2019    a2
test_fid1   5/8/2019    a3
test_fid1   5/9/2019    a3
test_fid1   5/10/2019   a3
```

I want to identify the date at which the stage column values starts and end e.g. test_fid has stage a1 from 4/22/2019 to 4/23/2019. The results should look like so:

```
fid        stage    start_date  end_date
test_fid    a1  4/22/2019   4/23/2019
test_fid    a2  4/24/2019   4/26/2019
test_fid    a3  4/27/2019   4/29/2019
test_fid1   a1  4/30/2019   5/3/2019
test_fid1   a2  5/4/2019    5/7/2019
test_fid1   a3  5/8/2019    5/10/2019
```

I tried this:

```
df['stage_change'] = df['stage'].diff()
df_filtered = df[df['stage_change'] != 0]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably forgot to parse your `date` column to a date object, you can do that, like [@pythonic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57548469/67579) said with:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Probably the most robust way to do this is calculating the minimum and maximum of the `date` for each group, like:

```
>>> df.groupby(['fid', 'stage'])['date'].agg({'start_date': 'min', 'end_date':'max'})
                    start_date       end_date
fid       stage                              
test_fid  a1         4/22/2019      4/23/2019
          a2         4/24/2019      4/26/2019
          a3         4/27/2019      4/29/2019
test_fid1 a1         4/30/2019       5/3/2019
          a2          5/4/2019       5/7/2019
          a3         5/10/2019       5/9/2019
```

Or if you do not wish to use `fid` and `stage` as index, you can reset the index:

```
>>> df.groupby(['fid', 'stage'])['date'].agg({'start_date': 'min', 'end_date':'max'}).reset_index()
         fid stage     start_date       end_date
0   test_fid    a1      4/22/2019      4/23/2019
1   test_fid    a2      4/24/2019      4/26/2019
2   test_fid    a3      4/27/2019      4/29/2019
3  test_fid1    a1      4/30/2019       5/3/2019
4  test_fid1    a2       5/4/2019       5/7/2019
5  test_fid1    a3      5/10/2019       5/9/2019
```

Comment: there is something wrong in your last line. Start_date is later then end_date. The problem here is that you use string comparison and not comparison on date times. Easiest way to solve it is probably to convert to datetimes first

Comment: `min` and `max` is actually the more safe solution here over `first` and `last`, but you didnt convert to datetime

Comment: Well, I sorted first by date, therefore both is equally save. Min & max is the more elegant solution though

Answer (score 3):

Use `sort_values` on date and `groupby`. Then aggregate for the first and last date.

`df.sort_values('date').groupby(['stage','fid']).agg({'date':['first', 'last']}).reset_index()`

result

```
    stage   fid date
                        first   last
0   a1  test_fid    2019-04-22  2019-04-23
1   a1  test_fid1   2019-04-30  2019-05-03
2   a2  test_fid    2019-04-24  2019-04-26
3   a2  test_fid1   2019-05-04  2019-05-07
4   a3  test_fid    2019-04-27  2019-04-29
5   a3  test_fid1   2019-05-08  2019-05-10
```

Edit: I first converted to datetime

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Comment: I think `sort_values['fid', 'date', 'stage'])` would be safer here

Comment: from the documentation of  the [documentation of groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html): **groupby preserves the order of rows within each group**. Therefore sorting by date should be enough